# Mormonism view on God as a physical being

Tags: nature-of-god, lds

According to the BBC website on religions.  Its states the following about the doctrine held by Mormonism about the physical body of God:

> Mormons believe that:
>
> God is an exalted, perfected man.
>
> God has a physical body.

[An explantation of Mormon beliefs about God.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/religion/religions/mormon/beliefs/god_1.shtml)

I really struggle with this concept and way of thinking about God.  I am seeking clarity on the subject as to why Mormons believe such a doctrine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

David,

Members of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints (colloq. Mormons) believe that we are literally spirit children of God, that He is an exalted being, and that we can become like Him.  Jesus Christ also has a physical body and He was the only begotten of The Father (God).  Our physical bodies were not begotten of The Father, but we are all His spirit children, and Christ is our brother.

Paul explained it clearly when he said, `"For in him we live, and move, and have our being; as certain also of your own poets have said, For we are also his offspring. Forasmuch then as we are the offspring of God, we ought not to think that the Godhead is like unto gold, or silver, or stone, graven by art and man’s device."` [Acts 17:29](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/acts/17.29?lang=eng#28)

There are many Bible and other LDS canonized scriptures to support this doctrine.  Here are some of the many references:

### King James Bible

- [Gen 1:27](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/gen/1.27) God created man image
- [Ps. 82:6](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/ps/82.6?lang=eng#5) Ye are gods, children of the most High:
- [Heb. 12:9](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/heb/12.9?lang=eng#8) Be in subjection unto the Father of spirits
- [Rom 8:16](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/rom/8.16?lang=eng#15) The Spirit itself beareth witness with our spirit, that we are the children of God
- [Phil. 3:21](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/philip/3.21?lang=eng#20) His glorified body
- [1 Jn 3:1-2](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/1-jn/3.1-2?lang=eng#0) Now are we the sons of God

### LDS Canonized Scriptures

**Book of Mormon**

- [Mosiah 5:7](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/mosiah/5.7?lang=eng#6) You shall be called the children of Christ, his sons and his daughters
- [Mosiah 27:25](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/mosiah/27.25?lang=eng#24) All people must be born again, becoming his sons and daughters
- [Ether 3:14](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/ether/3.14?lang=eng#13) They shall become my sons and my daughters
- [Moro. 7:19](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/moro/7.19?lang=eng#18) Ye certainly will become a child of Christ

**Pearl of Great Price**

[Moses 1:13](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/moses/1.13?lang=eng#12) I am a son of God

**Doctrine and Covenants**

[D&C 130:22](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/130.22?lang=eng#21) The Father has a body of flesh and bones as tangible as man’s

**Bonus**

There are many other Bible references to God and his physical body:

- [Gen 32:30](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/gen/32.30?lang=eng#29) His face
- [Ex. 24:10](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/ex/24.10?lang=eng#9) His feet
- [Ex. 31:18](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/ex/31.18?lang=eng#17) His finger
- [Num. 12:8](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/num/12.8?lang=eng#7) His mouth

Comment: Thank you JBaczuk.  I suppose I struggle with the concept of God being a physical being having always believed in Him as an invisible force.  I understand the scriptures suggest that He can manifest Himself as human but wonder whether these scriptures were to be taken less literally?  Thanks again.

Comment: @David see James 1:5

Comment: @JBaczuk...  indeed good sir,  a fine scripture, advice of which we humans often forget. Thankyou.